# Query Hangfire via internal API or Db Context?

Tags: c#, .net, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I wonder if there is an internal API or EF Context that i can use within hangfire? I would like to obtain a list of all the jobs that have failed, check the method they are for and then requeue them if they are for the method i require.

I would like to do this so that users can change the configuration of a job that has been queued but failed for whatever reason, and they can force it to run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with a monitoring API object, obtained through :

```
Hangfire.JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi()
```

and its `FailedJobs(int from, int count)` method